# Can somebody write this text in 3rd person omniscient

Tags: third-person

Father didn't seem to hear me. I'd never seen him so upset. What he said about Mother was true, but I couldn't make myself resent the long-ago Dwarf who had drawn those hands.

I pointed to the drawing in the center. "What is that creature called, Father? I've never seen one."

He shrugged. "And never will. It's a hydra — a nine-headed monster with poison breath. They died out ages ago. A good thing, too. They ate Dwarves. My grandfather told me about them. I didn't want to give you the nightmares I had."

I stared. To think that an Old One had drawn it. "It's like we're looking back in time." Father grunted. He began scraping one glowing hand with an adze, hoping to catch flakes of bright in a small pail. But none of the bryght came off. "It's been spread too thin for too many centuries. I won't give up, though. No child of long ago shall endanger Dwarves today."

"You think a child did this?"

"Who else?" Father asked. "Tracing around a hand, then drawing a picture of a creature that was almost extinct. Yet how could parents allow such nonsense with a priceless resource?"

I touched one of the glowing hands. "Are you sure it's not an adult's? Look how much smaller mine is." Father shrugged and started scraping again. "Perhaps the girl or boy wanted the hands to look larger. Who can know, so long afterward?"

I stepped closer to the wall. "When I was young, I used to draw. But my animals were just scribbles. This monster looks almost real enough to crawl off the wall. Could any child draw so well?"

"One with talent, unquestionably." Father's voice was as sharp as the tool he scraped across the stone. "Talent, but no sense."

He stepped back. "I'm getting nowhere. We'll need to take down most of the wall's surface. We can grind it down and sift out the bryght elsewhere. I'll get started while you fetch the others."

Something felt wrong, so wrong that for the first time in my life, I let myself openly disagree with Father. "I think an adult drew these pictures. Look how high up they are. And she or he must have had a good reason, or the bryght would have been removed long ago. Perhaps we should leave the wall alone."

Comment: Please share it you found out how to do it. My Gmail is merugulalithk@gmail.com or you can just comment it,too. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I'm afraid this site is for seeking advice on how to write better; we do not rewrite your stories for you.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that someone could do that for you. It will not be me. And I have reasons for that.

What you present in your question are the words. What is lacking is the writer's intent in writing those words. I assume that you have something to say and that you have come to this forum to fix problems with how you are saying it. There are many ways to re-write this material but only a few that would be true to that intent.

Here is what I would like to see in a question:

1. This is what I am trying to accomplish (theme, intent)
2. This is what I have tried (hopefully more than one thing)
3. This is the problem or deficiency as I see it (more than "it is wrong")
4. This is the criteria that I will use to judge the answer (more objective than subjective)

Please edit your question to provide the information that we need to answer it.